# Make UILabel Constraint to display full width

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

I'm struggling to implement to make my uilabel to stretch from the left side to right side (Full Width), I can do it easily in storyboard but I have a part on my app that needs to display a uilabel progmatically. 
Here's my code:

```
textLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
textLabel.text = StringsLabel.NOINTERNET
textLabel.textAlignment = .Center
textLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(24.0)
textLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
centerView.addSubview(textLabel)

let centreXTopLabel:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: centerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0);
        centerView.addConstraint(centreXTopLabel)
```

Here's the screenshot of what i've got:

[image]

Comment: You need to use AutoLayout, use NSLayoutConstraint or third party Masonry or SnapKit

Comment: Visual format language would be the way to go if you've got to do it programatically. Here's a tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/110393/auto-layout-visual-format-language-tutorial

Comment: The effect you are trying to achieve can happen if you put the UILabel in another UIView, add the full width constraints to that UIView, set its background colour to you required color. then add the UILabel in that View and center it in that UIView using constraints again. Currently your UILabel's background is grey it does not strech because it is what the size of text is

Answer (score 1):

Pin it to the leading and trailing of the view at 0 points:

```
let leading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textLabel, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: centerView, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let trailing = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textLabel, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: centerView, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([leading, trailing])
```

Note that this will result in an ambiguous layout — you need to add a constraint that positions the label vertically.

Comment: Hi, instead of using of this NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([leading, trailing]) i use this centerView.addConstraints([leading, trailing]) since I support ios7. But by the way the code you've posted doesn't work :(

Comment: the output still the same on the screenshot that i've posted above.

Comment: @SydneyLoteria Turns out the screenshot you've posted above is what you are describing (stretched from left to right). If you want a different effect, you aren't explaining it correctly.

Comment: the screenshot above is not even stretch as you can see the gray background covers the width only of the content of the label.

Comment: @SydneyLoteria Try setting the background color of `centerView`. How you set up the constraints for `centerView` may be the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106527/discussion-between-sydney-loteria-and-troyt).

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
let views = ["textLabel" : textLabel]
let formatString = "|-[textLabel]-|"

 let constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(formatString, options:.AlignAllTop , metrics: nil, views: views)

NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(constraints)
```